# How to find matching words using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp, regex-negation

I have strings in a text file with more than 2000 lines, like:

```
cool.add.come.ADD_COPY
add.cool.warm.ADD_IN
warm.cool.warm.MINUS
cool.add.go.MINUS_COPY
```

I have a list of more than 200 matching words, like:

```
store=['ADD_COPY','add.cool.warm.ADD_IN', 'warm.cool.warm.MINUS', 'MINUS_COPY']
```

I'm using regular expression in the code

```
def all(store, file):
    lst=[]
    for match in re.finditer(r'[\w.]+', file):
        words = match.group()
            if words in store:
                lst.append(words) 
    return lst
```

Then I check in a loop for requirement.

Output I'm getting:

```
add.cool.warm.ADD_IN
warm.cool.warm.MINUS
```

If I change the identifiers to `\w+` then I get only:

```
ADD_COPY
MINUS_COPY
```

Required output:

```
add.cool.warm.ADD_IN
warm.cool.warm.MINUS   
ADD_COPY
MINUS_COPY
```

Comment: @RishiDev Definitely not, `.` inside a character class always matches a literal `.`

Comment: This question has all the details to repro the issue. It just missed two colons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want to get the results using a mere list comprehension:

```
results = set([item for item in store if item in text])
```

If you need a regex (in case you plan to match whole words only, or match your `store` items only in specific contexts), you may get the matches using

```
import re
text="""cool.add.come.ADD_COPY
add.cool.warm.ADD_IN
warm.cool.warm.MINUS
cool.add.go.MINUS_COPY"""

store=['ADD_COPY','add.cool.warm.ADD_IN', 'warm.cool.warm.MINUS', 'MINUS_COPY']
rx="|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, store), key=len, reverse=True))
print(re.findall(rx, text))
```

The regex will look like

```
add\.cool\.warm\.ADD_IN|warm\.cool\.warm\.MINUS|MINUS_COPY|ADD_COPY
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q05C19/1), basically, all your `store` items with escaped special characters and sorted by length in the descending order.